# PHP sessions and cookies in a login system

Tags: php, authentication, session, cookies

I have read in a lot of places like, [`session_start()` creates a cookie](http://www.sitepoint.com/users-php-sessions-mysql/), [`session_start()` creates a cookie](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3472581)that under default configuration of php.ini `session_start()` creates generates a random `sessionID` and stores it in a cookie on the user's browser. However, I could not find any reference to this in [php.net](https://www.php.net/function.session-start). Is there a place where I can find some proper documentation and internal working of this?

Secondly, I want to understand a sequential step by step process of how a simple login system would look like in PHP in conjunction with the above, i.e session, the `sessionID` generated and the associated cookie set by `session_start()`. Please help providing a step-by-step process of this flow, like :- (Assuming that user User1 is already registered into the system and now he is trying to access a page which needs him to be logged into the system)

1. User1 clicks the URL hxxp://restrictedPage.php (for example)
2. System checks and see that User1 is not logged in - meaning say system checks to see if there is a valid sessionID apparently in place here. (So what exactly would be checked ?)
3. Since the check (which I need help with) in step 2 fails user is redirected to login.php (say for example) that has the login form.
4. On the login form user enters username and password and submits the POST form.
5. Server side - authenticateUser.php (say for example) verifies the `$_POST['userName']` and `$_POST['password']` with the db values. Let's assume that this checks returns true, i.e the username and password supplied by the user was correct.
6. What happens now from here on? Where does the session come into picture and when is the cookie with the `sessionID` created? When is it sent to the browser?
7. Now when the session is in place (which I need help with understanding how exactly) and the user comes to a landing page after the login, say, welcome.php which also has a link to restrictedPage.php and now when the user clicks on this link, how exactly is the session validated on the server? I mean the cookie holding the `sessionID` would be sent with this request, but where is it cross checked with the `sessionID` already present on the server? Is it done explicitly (like we do for validating username and password from db) or is it taken care of automatically by PHP?

Comment: See the source for internals: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/71ad601deef5df51192788049838e6c3d7d88c5d/ext/session/session.c#L1487

Comment: Thanks for indicating the internals @Piskvor. I would appreciate if you could provide inputs on the second section of the question as well.

Comment: @geek_ji giveme a sec ill write you a complete login system, with full documentation for every step.

Comment: Why downvote, the question is ok, but it would be good if we could see any attempts. (own code, not linked) nvm i wrote an answer, i hope it helps

Comment: @geek_ji I think your confusing something which is, the php session id is not **sent** to the client its **received** as part of the response headers, then the client/browser resends the id with subsequent requests. session_start will set the headers as soon as its called, this is why you cant call session_start after output.

Comment: @LozCherone The ID is SENT to the client via a response. So it is SENT. The visitor gets a response which contains a cookie, this cookie contains a value, which is the visitor's SESSIONID. BUT you can use sessions without using COOKIES, but this makes the sessionid shown to the client several ways.

Comment: @newboyhun: I have not seen a cookieless session system in PHP for at least ten years; while still technically possible, it's a massive hassle (and contains several security pitfalls, as you're exposing the session ID everywhere)

Comment: @Piskvor I didn't say to use it, I say DON'T use it, i just mentioned it.

Comment: @newboyhun its not sent like the server makes another TCP/IP connection to the client and sends it using a socket, its sent as in the response packet the client receives, which is what I said.

Comment: this may be useful: [the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication).

Answer (score 1):

The session (and its cookie, if none exists yet) is created right at the beginning, when you call `session_start()`; it is sent to the browser with the response, via the response-header [Set-Cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Implementation)

A valid session ID only says "This browser has requested a page from me before", nothing more: PHP checks if a session by that name exists (see the source to see how *exactly* this happens, but this is not interesting for normal use), and deserializes it into `$_SESSION`.

It is up to *you* to couple this with authentication, authorization and identification - usually, the login functionality checks username and password, and if correct, sets a session variable "this is user 1234":

```
if ($is_login) {
    // in real use you would check the username & password against a db
    if ($username == "Piskvor" && $password == "123456") {
        $_SESSION['user'] = 789;
    } else {
        // bad username or password
        $_SESSION['user'] = 0;
    }
} else if ($is_logout) {
    // logout this user from session
    $_SESSION['user'] = 0;
}
```

Then in a restricted section, you can check the session variable:

```
if (is_numeric($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] > 0) {
    do_something_super_secret();
} else {
    redirect_to_login();
}
```

In other words, PHP only creates/restores the `$_SESSION` array for you, based on the session cookie. It is completely up to you to build something (such as authentication) on top of this.

Comment: I understand this case when we are using session variables. But I am trying to understand the same thing with the cookie that gets sent and what role does it play in the login as we are not cross checking it explicitly anywhere. Are we ?

Comment: The cookie only serves as an identifier for the session, *nothing more*: "Your session ID is 1234567890," everything else is stored server-side in the session. The session ID is not validated automatically (you'd need to do this yourself), PHP considers any session ID valid.

Answer (score 0):

Huh? I don't see what is the real problem here.

When you create a session, it is saved on the server within a folder. (Configurable)

The cookie is important (There is no other way to check which session belongs to the visitor), so this is the only way to save things.

Mostly you don't have to care about things like this. (session)

When the user presses the login button in a form, then the following happens in PHP on the server:

1. The data of the form is in the `$_POST` global  as an associative array with  `["form's input name" => "form's input Value", ...]`
2. You check that if the value is valid or not, if valid, compare the values to the database's values
3. Login:

   1. Successful login, you set a session about the login data. (ex.: `$_SESSION["login"] = array("id" => $id, "username" => $un, "password" => $pw);` ) Don't forget to encrypt the password (never save plain password into db)
   2. The login failed, show an error to the visitor.
4. The user is logged in, server compares the data in the session against the db values

   1. Values are valid; continue
   2. Values aren't equal to the db values, log out the user ( delete the session: `unset($_SESSION["login"])` )
5. The visitor visits the `restricedPage.php` if the session data is 1) valid and 2) EXISTS, then continue, otherwise redirect to 404 or to a visitor page.

Edit:

A cookie is set by session_start(), so you the server can find the session assigned to the visitor (`sessionid`).

Every configuration for the cookie can be found in the PHP's configuration.

The cookies value contains a single 'character sequence' (?) which is the visitors session's id. (If you know other visitor's session's id you can change your cookie's value to the other visitor's one, so never make the ID public in any form.)

You can get the cookie's params by the 'session_get_cookie_params()'.

> Returns an array with the current session cookie information, the
> array contains the following items:
>
> "lifetime" - The lifetime of the cookie in seconds. "path" - The path
> where information is stored. "domain" - The domain of the cookie.
> "secure" - The cookie should only be sent over secure connections.
> "httponly" - The cookie can only be accessed through the HTTP
> protocol.

The quote is from the PHP's documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-get-cookie-params.php

Comment: i was not referring to setting a cookie explicitly. I was talking about the cookie that is auto set by session_start(). Can you provide inputs on that ? That's the whole point of the confusion.